# Finding a grammar for $L = \{ 0^x1^y0^z1^w | x+w=y+z\}$

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

I have found an exercise where it tasks to provide a grammar and a pushdown automata for
$L = \{ 0^x1^y0^z1^w | x+w=y+z\}$

While finding a pushdown automata for it is quite easy (four states and two stack symbols $p$ and $t$, where $0^x$'s push $p$, $1^t$'s and $0^z$'s pop $p$ or push $t$ if there are no $p$'s, and $1^w$'s pop $t$), I am unable to find an equivalent grammar for it. Perhaps there is some trick for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's write the condition $x+w=y+z$ in a different way: $x-y=z-w$. We consider two cases: $x \geq y$ and $y \geq x$. If $x \geq y$, let $x = y+a$. Then we are interested in words of the form
$$
0^{y+a} 1^y 0^{w+a} 1^w = 0^a 0^y 1^y 0^a 0^w 1^w.
$$
If $y \geq x$, let $y=x+b$. Then we are interested in words of the form
$$
0^x 1^{x+b} 0^z 1^{z+b} = 0^x 1^x 1^b 0^z 1^z 1^b.
$$
We can generate words of the first form using the grammar
\begin{align}
&T_1 \to AW \\
&A \to 0A0 \mid Y \\
&Y \to 0Y1 \mid \epsilon \\
&W \to 0W1 \mid \epsilon
\end{align}
We can generate words of the second form using the grammar
\begin{align}
&T_2 \to XB \\
&X \to 0X1 \mid \epsilon \\
&B \to 1B1 \mid Z \\
&Z \to 0Z1 \mid \epsilon
\end{align}
Taking these two grammars together and adding a new rule $S \to T_1 \mid T_2$, we get a grammar for your language. Note that you can merge $X,Y,Z,W$. The resulting grammar is
\begin{align}
&S \to AX \mid XB \\
&A \to 0A0 \mid X \\
&B \to 1B1 \mid X \\
&X \to 0X1 \mid \epsilon
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if $x$, $y$, etc. can be $0$, so maybe there's something to fix (e.g., you'll need $S\rightarrow \varepsilon$ etc.), but you can try something like this:

$S\rightarrow 0S1 \mid 0A0 \mid 1B1 $
$A \rightarrow 0A0 \mid 1C0$
$B \rightarrow 1B1 \mid 1C0$
$C \rightarrow 1C0 \mid \varepsilon$

Suppose $w\geq x$, then the idea is first generating the string $0^x S' 1^x$, then adding $w-x$ $1$'s on the right of the first $0$'s and the same number of $0$'s on the left of the last $1$'s, and so on; the case $x\geq w$ is similar.